# Migration of PIPELINED from Oracle to Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Creation of TYPE is as follows:

```
create or replace  Type T_dates as OBJECT(
p_st_date VARCHAR2(32767),
p_en_date VARCHAR2(32767) 
);
create or replace  TYPE T_dates_tab AS table of T_dates;
```

Sample Code which needs to convert is as follows.
Oracle Code:

```
Function f_get_dates(p_st_date varchar2,
                     p_end_date varchar2,
                     p_st_time varchar2,
                     p_end_time varchar2) 
return  T_dates_tab PIPELINED 
IS 

V_DAY_COUNT NUMBER;
P_TEMP_ST_DATE VARCHAR2(100 ):=p_st_date;
BEGIN
    SELECT TO_DATE(p_end_date,'MM-DD-YYYY ') - TO_DATE(p_temp_st_date,'MM-DD-YYYY ') INTO V_DAY_COUNT FROM DUAL ;
    WHILE V_DAY_COUNT >= 0
    LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_temp_st_date||' '||p_st_time||','||p_temp_st_date||' '||p_end_time);
      PIPE ROW (T_dates((p_temp_st_date||' '||p_st_time),(p_temp_st_date||' '||p_end_time)));
      SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(p_temp_st_date,'MM-DD-YYYY')+1,'MM/DD/YYYY') INTO p_temp_st_date FROM DUAL;
      SELECT TO_DATE(p_end_date,'MM-DD-YYYY ') - TO_DATE(p_temp_st_date,'MM-DD-YYYY ') INTO V_DAY_COUNT FROM DUAL ;

    END LOOP;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('f_get_dates');
    RETURN;

END f_get_dates;
```

Need Postgres Inputs for the above Oracle code.

Comment: Why are you returning date values as `VARCHAR`? That is a horrible idea.

Comment: It is written in Source Database so need to replicate same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function can be massively simplified in Postgres. In fact you don't really need your own function for that:

```
select p_st_date::date + time '00:00:00' as p_st_date, 
       p_st_date::date + time '18:00:00' as p_en_date
from generate_series(date '2018-01-01', date '2018-01-30', interval '1' day) as t(p_st_date);
```

In contrast to your function this returns real timestamp values rather than character values. If you indeed want to treat timestamp values as character data, use `to_char()` to convert that.

You can put the above into a SQL function:

```
create function f_get_dates(p_st_date date, p_en_date date, p_st_time time, p_end_time time) 
  returns table (p_st_date timestamp, p_en_date timestamp)
as
$$
select p_st_date::date + p_st_time as p_st_date, 
       p_st_date::date + p_end_time as p_en_date
from generate_series(p_st_date, p_en_date, interval '1' day) as t(p_st_date);
$$
language sql;
```

If you really want to return the timestamps as character values, just format them using to_char():

```
create function f_get_dates(p_st_date date, p_en_date date, p_st_time time, p_end_time time) 
  returns table (p_st_date varchar, p_en_date varchar)
as
$$
select to_char(p_st_date::date + p_st_time, 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as p_st_date, 
       to_char(p_st_date::date + p_end_time, 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as p_en_date
from generate_series(p_st_date, p_en_date, interval '1' day) as t(p_st_date);
$$
language sql;
```

Comment: It works. But while migration need to have code with replacement of PIPE ROW. Thank you.

Comment: I Need to have code which uses TYPES for the above mentioned Oracle Code. Help me in this.

Comment: @lakshmisowmya: the equivalent to `PIPE ROW` is `return next` in PL/pgSQL but that is very inefficient. And you don't need the cumbersome workaround with TYPES in Postgres to be able to return a set from a function. Why do you want to keep that?